# onsubmit form validation. Form submits even though there are errors

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I created a registration page, and each field requires entry and validation. I used the onsubmit event to call my js function to validate the form if the field is empty, however it still submits even though it has not been validated properly.

```js
function validate() {
  var streetName = document.getElementById("sN").value;


  if (streetName == "" || streetName == null || streetName == undefined) {
    window.alert("Sorry");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForms" action="https://httpbin.org/post " method="post" class="form" onsubmit="return validate()">

  <div id="fN">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name" required>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="lN">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name" required="">
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="sN">
    <label>Street name</label>
    <input type="text" name="streetname" placeholder="Enter your street name">
  </div>



  // Somemore inputs

  <input class="buttons" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up" onclick="validate()">

</form>
```

I expect a window to pop up saying "this entry is wrong and for this reason", but it submits anyway

EDIT: I apologize I should've been clearer in my post. I will use required in some of the inputs, however I will eventually need to write js code to ensure a phone number is all digits and password = passwordconfirm and a postal code is an actual postal code. In the JS file I just showed what I basically tried doing.

Comment: if you just wanted to validate on empty inputs, just use html5's required value, **<input type="text" name="streetname" placeholder="Enter your street name" required>**

Comment: I apologize I should've been clearer in my post. I will use required in some of the inputs, however I will eventually need to write js code to ensure a phone number is all digits and password = passwordconfirm and a postal code is an actual postal code. In the JS file I just showed what I basically tried doing.

Comment: *<div class="sN">* is what you have and your JS expects *<div id="sN">* **or** use in your js **var streetName = document.getElementsByClassName("sN").value;**

Comment: @Vishwa the div has the class and no value

Comment: @user11290952 i would suggest you try type = "button" instead of "submit"

Comment: @mplungjan — getElementsByClassName returns a NodeList, not an element.

Comment: @Quentin I know, missed that too.Even worse then

Comment: @mplungjan — Well, I managed to type your name instead of Vishwa's so I'm doing really well too!

Comment: @imdisney why? Then the form will not submit if correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things

1. You have validate on the submit AND on the form submit
2. You should NEVER call anything in a form "submit" since it will hide the submit event/method
3. You need to get the correct field
4. Give the form an ID and use unobtrusive code like this

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    var errors = false;
    var streetName = this.streetname.value.trim(); // no more action needed
    if (!streetName) errors = true;
    // more validations
    if (errors) {
      window.alert("Sorry");
      e.preventDefault();
    }  
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="https://httpbin.org/post " method="post" class="form">
  <div id="fN">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name" >
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="lN">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name" >
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="sN">
    <label>Street name</label>
    <input type="text" name="streetname" placeholder="Enter your street name">
  </div>

  <input class="buttons" type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Sign up">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var streetName = document.getElementById("sN").value;
> ```

There is no element with that `id` in the document.

There is an element with `sN` as its *class name*, but `getElementById` won't find an element by its class and the `value` of `<div class="sN">` will **always** be `undefined`. It is the `input` that will have a value.

Comment: Not the only problem with this script